# Strange mod operator behavior in metapost

Tags: context, metapost, metafun

I am currently facing a strange behavior of the metapost `mod` operator.

Here is a simple piece of code:

```tex
\startMPcode
    for x = 0 step .5 until 10:
      if (x mod 1) = 0.5: label.top(x, (x*cm, 0cm)) ; fi
    endfor
\stopMPcode
```

producing the following result

[image: first result]

which is what is expected.

Now let's change the step to `0.1`

```tex
\startMPcode
    for x = 0 step .1 until 10:
      if (x mod 1) = 0.5: label.top(x, (x*cm, 0cm)) ; fi
    endfor
\stopMPcode
```

and try it again, we then get the following result

[image: second result]

instead of the above.

What happens here? Why are the results different?

Comment: Try to add `message(x mod 1) ;` inside the for loop.

Comment: Oh ! I do not ever get `0.y` exactly but `0.z999999999...`. What should I do then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rounding error, as noticed in the comments. This problem is not unique to MetaPost, it occurs in all programming languages that implement floating point arithmetic.

One solution is to multiply by ten and then use integer rounding with the `round()` function. To prevent the 0.00000n output in the label you can do the same trick by multiplying, rounding, then dividing.

Standalone MetaPost MWE:

```
prologues:=3;
beginfig(1);
for x = 0 step .1 until 10:
  if round((x mod 1) * 10) = 5: label.top(decimal(round(x * 10)/10), (x*cm, 0cm)) ; fi
endfor
endfig;
end
```

Comment: Metapost (like Metafont) does not use floating point arithmetic, but a fixed point binary representation for numbers. It's still true that there is no exact representation of numbers like 1/10.

Answer (score 5):

Noninteger arithmetic in Metapost is peculiar.

You may try passing `-numbersystem=decimal` as runtime option. With it from the code

```
for x = 0 step .1 until 2:
  show (x mod 1) ;
endfor
```

I get

```
>> 0
>> 0.1
>> 0.2
>> 0.3
>> 0.4
>> 0.5
>> 0.6
>> 0.7
>> 0.8
>> 0.9
>> 0
>> 0.1
>> 0.2
>> 0.3
>> 0.4
>> 0.5
>> 0.6
>> 0.7
>> 0.8
>> 0.9
>> 0
```

Alternatively, use integers and scale after the test.